# How do I get the functions put and get in SICP, Scheme, Exercise 2.78 and on

Tags: scheme, sicp

I am trying to do exercise 2.78 in SICP, but the functions put and get are unknown. I have tried multiple languages, like pretty big, racket, r5rs, mit-scheme, mzscheme, etc. I even downloaded the SICP support (http://www.neilvandyke.org/sicp-plt/), to no avail. How can I get these functions to work?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, I found SICP a little annoying sometimes because of stuff like this. Functions that are assumed to exist but don't actually exist make it harder to try to the examples. I wrote my own (get) and (put) like so (this was in GNU guile):

```
(define global-array '())

(define (make-entry k v) (list k v))
(define (key entry) (car entry))
(define (value entry) (cadr entry))

(define (put op type item)
  (define (put-helper k array)
    (cond ((null? array) (list(make-entry k item)))
          ((equal? (key (car array)) k) array)
          (else (cons (car array) (put-helper k (cdr array))))))
  (set! global-array (put-helper (list op type) global-array)))

(define (get op type)
  (define (get-helper k array)
    (cond ((null? array) #f)
          ((equal? (key (car array)) k) (value (car array)))
          (else (get-helper k (cdr array)))))
  (get-helper (list op type) global-array))
```

Probably a naive implementation from the perspective of later in the book, but fairly simple and worked fine.

Answer (score 10):

There is an implementation of **put** and **get** by [Eli Bendersky](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2007/09/09/sicp-section-24/).
These functions could be implemented using builtin [Basic Hash Table Operations](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Basic-Hash-Table-Operations.html). Here is my modified version of Eli's code to work properly with MIT-Scheme Release 9.1.1.

```
(define *op-table* (make-hash-table))

(define (put op type proc)
  (hash-table/put! *op-table* (list op type) proc))

(define (get op type)
  (hash-table/get *op-table* (list op type) '()))
```

**UPDATED**:

I've found bug with above mentioned code after time. Empty lists are interpreted as `true` in conditional clauses by Scheme, so correct `get` implementation should be following:

```
(define (get op type)
  (hash-table/get *op-table* (list op type) #f))
```

Answer (score 7):

If you use Racket programming language please use these:

```
(define *op-table* (make-hash))

(define (put op type proc)
  (hash-set! *op-table* (list op type) proc))

(define (get op type)
  (hash-ref *op-table* (list op type) '()))
```

Answer (score 2):

In subsection `Creating local tables` of `3.3.3 Representing Tables`, there is an implementation.

Answer (score 2):

mit-scheme has a built-in global table that you can use.

http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/The-Association-Table.html

simply define get and put to:

```
(define get 2d-get)
(define put 2d-put!)
```

Comment: 2d-get and 2d-put! complain when providing list arguments for the x-key and y-key parameters, in that sense it's better to use the hash-table implementation.

Comment: @MathieuBorderé  Do they use `get` and `put` with lists later in the chapter?

Comment: To my question, yes, they use it for exercise 2.77.

Comment: So it's better to use this answer, also works for MIT Scheme: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19114031/816449