# Prerequisite for SICP

Tags: sicp

I have been programming in a "learn-by-doing" fashion for almost 2 years now and I consider myself fairly good however, I really wish to build a good foundation of Computer Science/Computer Engineering and most people recommend I start off with SICP. (Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs)

I wished to know

- Is this the best way to go about it?
- I know how to code a matrix-multiplication in OpenMP and MPI and I know college level math, is this sufficient to read and appreciate SICP?
- Instead of this, can I just spend all my time working on Project Euler instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A personal experience: Like you I am trying to learn programming by self-study and I started off with SICP. As I am a ancient historian and archaeologist, I have no background in maths, engineering or real computer science (just good knowlegde in stuff like LaTeX, HTML and CSS). My last lessons in math are now 15 years ago. Although I am working through SICP with a math book at my side the explanations given in SICP are really sufficient to understand the stuff. I really appreciate SICP, it is demanding, but great fun. I also would recommend to buy it as a book, I prefer that from reading on screen.

Sometimes you have to cope with some difficulties because language standards have changed (eg. [Running SICP Pattern Matching Rule Based Substitution Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970006/running-sicp-pattern-matching-rule-based-substitution-code)) or the authors assume existing functions which are just defined later in the book (eg. [How do I get the functions put and get in SICP, Scheme, Exercise 2.78 and on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499005/how-do-i-get-the-functions-put-and-get-in-sicp-scheme-exercise-2-78-and-on)). As a you always will find solutions or hints on the web this is nothing which should bother you.

Comment: I want to add, there is a package for `DrRacket` that implements Scheme dialect used in SICP book. http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket-sicp/

Answer (score 1):

If you know any amount of programming you'll likely be better off for it, but it's by no means a requirement when going through the SICP. I'm going through it right now (cover to cover style), and I'm up too section 2.3.3. The biggest road block for me has been how maths based some of the problems can be, as it's been a while since I did maths back in high school. For these problems I've resorted to googling an explanation of the problem and solution. Like programming, maths isn't a requirement either, obviously because I'm still making progress through the book, but I feel it could help at times.

The only requirement you'll honestly need, is a computer and a scheme implementation, I'd recommend MIT scheme or DrRacket.

#### TL;DR

The only requirement you'll need is a computer, and a scheme implementation, everything else can be learned as you go along.